# Running Command Line from python to generate barcode

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, barcode

I'm trying to generate barcode using [Zint Barcode Studio](http://www.zint.org.uk/Manual.aspx?type=p&page=4) through command line . Using cmd.exe of windows I can do this using the following code :

```
F:\Zint>zint -o .\qr\datamatrix.png -b 20 --notext -d "Data to encode"
```

How can I run this command from python ??

I tried this , but no luck

```
from subprocess import call

dir1=r'F:\Zint\zint.exe'

cmd1='zint -o .\qr\datamatrix.png -b 20 --notext -d "Data to encode"'
rc=call(cmd1,cwd=dir1)
```

Please help me to run this command from python

Answer (score 1):

With subprocess.call() you enter your command as a list:

`cmd1 = ['zint' '-o', '.\qr\datamatrix.png', '-b', '20', '--notext', '-d', 'data_to_encode_goes_here']`

Note that in recent version of Python, subprocess.run() is the new standard (I don't see your version specified). It also takes a list as the command and not a string.

```
import os
import subprocess
out_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'qr')
if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
    os.makedirs(out_dir)
out_file = os.path.join(out_dir, 'datamatrix.png')
cmd1 = ['zint' '-o', out_file, '-b', '20', '--notext', '-d', '"data_to_encode_goes_here"']
rc = subprocess.call(cmd1)
```

Try something like that

Comment: Hi Lost , :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Card 05-06-2018/cmd_python.py", line 16, in <module>
    rc=call(cmd1,cwd=dir1)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: It may be that it's having trouble parsing your destination file name. Maybe `import os` and then instead of .\qr\datamatrix.png try putting: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'qr', 'datamatrix.png')`

Comment: Hi Lost , no luck , still same error. can you write full code for me please ?